# How to position the legend to the right of the donut chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Here is my [plunkr code](http://plnkr.co/edit/EW0k581XFBIeelwonwl2?p=preview), in this position of the legend is at center, how do I position it to the right of the donut chart?

```
var svg = d3.select('#chart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2 - radius) +
        ',' + (height / 2 - radius) + ')');
```

I tried with the above code but it's not working.

Comment: Provide a jsFiddle ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/EW0k581XFBIeelwonwl2?p=preview

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nx4aph3w/ JS Fiddle

Comment: @vishnu check this version of jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nx4aph3w/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define new variable and set your legend width in pixels:

```
var legendWidth = 150;
```

Use this variable for `svg` element width:

```
var svg = d3.select('#chart')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + legendWidth) // <== !!!
  .attr('height', height)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) +
    ',' + (height / 2) + ')');
```

Rewrite your function for legend `transform` attribute this way:

```
var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
  .data(color.domain())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'legend')
  .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
    var offset =  height * color.domain().length / 2;
    var vert = i * height - offset;
    return 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + vert + ')'; // <== move every legend item on half of width
  });
```

Check [working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/7oa6tj6u/).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nx4aph3w/1/) version of your jsfiddle. I have corrected some calculation to show legend on right side. highlighted code change below.

```
// For increasing horizontal space
var width = 600;

// For arranging chart in full space
var svg = d3.select('#chart')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 4) + 
        ',' + (height / 2) + ')');

// For moving legend to right
var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
  .data(color.domain())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'legend')
  .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
     var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
     var offset =  height * color.domain().length / 2;
     var horz = 7 * legendRectSize;
```